# Oracle truncate table takes to long for 300 million row table

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, truncate

Sometimes the truncate table takes to long. 
I have the following command with in a PL/SQL procedure. Is there any code I need before this or to included in the below statement to make this quicker. I'm re-inserting records into this table after the truncate which maybe around 500,000. The table does have 5 indexes but does not have any triggers.

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE act_plus_triggers';
```

Comment: Try `TRUNCATE TABLE act_plus_triggers DROP STORAGE` - is it faster?

Comment: I have never known a TRUCATE take longer than a few seconds. perhaps you have a lock on the table and it is waiting on the lock being released.

Comment: How do you know it is this statement that takes a long time? Do you **ever** get long execution times to truncate if you execute `truncate table ...` **directly on the database** (through SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad etc.)? How do you know it is not something else in the PL/SQL code that takes a long time?

Comment: it's the only thing i'm executing in the PL/SQL block

Comment: Please define _"too long"_.

Comment: Is this a single instance system or RAC? When you are re-loading your data, drop the indexes first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ErsinGülbahar's deleted answer is likely correct - the table or related object is likely locked by some other process.  `TRUNCATE` is a DDL command created to be almost infinitely faster than a regular `DELETE`.  If the command doesn't return within a few seconds then something weird is probably happening.

In *most* systems, a blocking lock would cause `TRUNCATE` to immediately throw an error message:

```
--Run in session #1:
drop table test1;
create table test1(a number);
insert into test1 values(1);
commit;

--Run in session #2:
update test1 set a = 2;
--Do *NOT* commit the results.

--Run in session #1, it will generate:
--ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
truncate table test1;
```

However, if your session or system has DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT set, then the session will wait for the resource to be available.

```
--Run in session #1.  This will wait either a long time or until the other session commits.
alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 100000;
truncate table test1;
```

To troubleshoot this, start by looking for who is blocking the session:

```
select sid, final_blocking_session, gv$session.*
from gv$session
where final_blocking_session is not null;
```